# How to count the number of relationships to a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, erd, relations

I am arranging an ERD diagram of an existing database with about a 100 tables, to add some structure to the process, how rank out the number of relations the tables have to each other?
For example, table 1 is related directly to ten tables. Table 2 is related to four tables and so on.

I am using MySQL workbench and the diagram is drawing using the programs Reverse Engineer on an existing database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select referenced_table_name, count(distinct constraint_name) 
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where referenced_table_schema=? 
and constraint_name <> 'PRIMARY' 
group by referenced_table_name;
```

I put `?` for the schema name, you would supply a query parameter for the schema you need to analyze.

Note that this works only if you have FOREIGN KEY constraints defined. If you don't have such constraints, there is no way for any tool to guess at the table relationships.

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qia6Mmtm)

Comment: Some of the results to the query are shown as 1 when there are two relations to a table

Comment: I added a clarification that this requires foreign key constraints, and I included a dbfiddle to demonstrate.